# Java JFrame distance between ovals not equal

Tags: java, swing, jframe, pixel, oval

I had to implement a JFrame with the size of 500 x 500 pixels that should have a 9 x 9 "field" of circles, but as you can see in the picture the distance between the first line of ovals and the second line of ovals is not equal.

[image]

The diameter should be 20 pixel and the distance between the center of one oval to another oval should be 40 pixel, but I don't know if I did this correctly:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class KreisFrame extends JFrame {
    public KreisFrame() {

        //Set JFrame size
        setSize(500,500);

        //Make JFrame visible
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        for (int j = 0; j < 500; j += 60){
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i += 60) {
                // draw circle
                g.drawOval(i, 20, 20, 20);
                g.drawOval(i, j, 20, 20);
                // fill circle
                g.fillOval(i, 20, 20, 20);
                g.fillOval(i, j, 20, 20);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        KreisFrame myframe = new KreisFrame();
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: First, please override `paintComponent()` not `paint()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Comment: Also please check your requirements: a 9x9 grid of circles offset by 60 pixels will need 560 pixels, not 500, or it won't fit.  I think your problem relates to this.  You're having to squish the last row in.

Comment: Or... 40 pixels apart on centers means the circles should be offset by 40 pixels, not 60.

Comment: @markspace Tried both, but they don't seem to fix it...

Comment: `g.drawOval(i, 20, 20, 20);` and `g.fillOval(i, 20, 20, 20);` What are these lines for? The  drawOval(int x, int y, int width, int height) method indicates that every time through the inner loop, you are creating an oval at y=20.

Comment: Not that it is part of your question, like @markspace says, they should be 40 apart. Testing for j < 500 and testing for i < 500 is a bad way to do this since you need a 9x9. j should go from 0 to < 9 and so should i. then you `g.drawOval(i * 40, j * 40, 20, 20)`. That is not going to be centered on your 500x500 canvas as it should take up only 340. So maybe you want something like `g.drawOval(i * 40 + 80, j * 40 + 80, 20, 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really subclass a JPanel, not the JFrame. And all of this should be done on the EventDispatchThread, not the main thread. Further, don't use "magic" numbers like 500, 20, and 40. Here's a solution that paints the entire panel, regardless of what size it is (note that there is no provision here for having a border on the panel).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Kreis extends JPanel {
   protected int dia = 20;
   protected int sep = 40;

   public Kreis() {

      // Set JFrame size
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      setBackground(Color.green);
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      Dimension d = getSize();

      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      for (int y = 0; y < d.height; y += sep) {
         for (int x = 0; x < d.width; x += sep) {
            // draw circle
            g.fillOval(x, y, dia, dia);
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(final String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // Create and set up the window.
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();

            Kreis panel = new Kreis();
            jf.add(panel);
            jf.pack();
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void windowClosing( WindowEvent arg0) {
                  System.exit(0);
               }
            });
         }
      });
   }
}
```